# backbone.js set model internal attributes hash directly

Tags: backbone.js

Using Backbone.js I know it's highly recommended to set a model's property using the [set](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-set) method, and NOT by directly modifying the [attributes internal hash](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-attributes).

However, apart from not firing the "change" event automatically, what other cons or "side-effects" are there in modifying the internal hash directly?

The problem I'm facing is that while the set method takes an object literal, I need to assign the left hand side using a variable determined at run-time. Thanks.

```js
myModel.set({
    myProperty : myValue; //myProperty is a variable, so this is invalid syntax
})

//vs

myModel.attributes[myProperty] = myValue; //myProperty is a variable that can be evaluated
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, if you look at the [annotated source code](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-28), you'll find that `set` does a lot.

What if you extended Backbone.Model with a function that does it for you:

```
Backbone.Model.prototype.setByName = function(key, value, options) { 
    var setter = {}; 
    setter[key] = value; 
    this.set(setter, options); 
};
```

Then, you can just do what you want directly on the model:

```
var model = new Backbone.Model();
model.setByName(myProperty, "bar");
```

That feels like a better solution to me.

**Edit**

As @earl3s pointed out, this is no longer necessary in more recent versions of Backbone.  Today, you can just call `model.set(myProperty, "bar")` and it does what you want.

Comment: I think your solution is brilliant. This function should be merged into newer Backbone releases! Thanks also for pointing out the annotated source code; you're right I should have looked at it in the first place.

Comment: nice! i've written this code a dozen times and never thought to make it a method. :) btw: there's no need to use _.extend for this. `Backbone.Model.prototype.setByName = function(...){...}` does the same thing... functionally the same. just a different way to do it.

Comment: @Derick Bailey: Funny... I thought that `_.extend` had some extra smarts for extending prototypes... nope.  It is really for extending any object with a collection of changes.  Nothing crazy there.  Changing my answer to acknowledge that.  Thanks.

Comment: This functionality is already built into the `set` method.  Why add it again?  You can write `model.set(stringProp, value)` or `model.set({prop:value})`.

Comment: @earl3s Well, your second method doesn't work if you don't know the name of `prop` (ie. prop is a variable).  IIRC, two years ago (~0.5.0), when I wrote this, you could only `set` with an object literal (your first mechanism wasn't available) so this was the only way.  I will update my answer.

Answer (score 7):

In the [annotated source code](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-28) mentioned by Brian Genisio you can read the following lines:
"Handle both "key", value and {key: value} -style arguments.".
So you can just use model.set(myProperty,"bar",options).
Perhaps they've added this feature after the post of Brian Genisio.. i dunno.

Comment: This is the correct solution.  The functionality already exists on the `set` method.