# how to listen to array submodel's value change

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

I have a model define like below.

```
var A = Backbone.Model.extends({
    initialize: function(){
       this.on('change:users.name',this.onUserNameChanged)
    },
    onUserNameChanged: function(){ alert('name changed')
});
var a = new A ({
   id:1,
   name:'test',
   users:[
   {
      id:2,
      name:'u1'
   },
   {
      id:3,
      name:'u4'
   }
  ]
  })
```

I want add event on the each user name change in Model define.
I have no idea to do this.It's seems hard to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you can't get change events by manipulating Backbone model array members as is described here:

[backbone-js-set-model-array-property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325004/backbone-js-set-model-array-property)

Your best option is to set the whole array and listen to a `change:users` event or even better - come up with a different model that has a Backbone collection for users that will get the event when manipulated:

```
var A = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function (options) {
        _.extend(this, options);
    }
});
var Users = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.on('change:name', function () {
            alert('name changed');
        });
    }
});

var a = new A({
    id: 1,
    name: 'test',
    users: new Users([{
        id: 2,
        name: 'u1'
    }, {
        id: 3,
        name: 'u4'
    }])
});

a.users.get('2').set('name', 'u2');
```

Comment: It's seems i must redefine the json parse to complex object.