# Set values to the folded defaults in Backbone.Model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, syntax, model, initialization

I have an object inside defaults like this:

```
app.MultiwidgetModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults : {
        ....
        operatorData        : {
                helloBlock  : null, 
                greeting    : null, 
                avatarBlock : null, 
                avatarImg   : null  
            },
        ....    
    },
    initialize: function(){
        ....
    }
});
```

How can I set values to the operatorData inner properties (helloBlock, greeting) etc in the initialize function? If it is possible, what syntax should I use?

Comment: You could use https://github.com/afeld/backbone-nested plugin

Comment: possible duplicate: [backbone.js set model array property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325004/backbone-js-set-model-array-property)

Comment: Artem, why plugin? Why not just to use 
this.get('operatorData').helloBlock = [value]
 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to set values to the current model in initialize and trigger the approriate `change` events, this should work:

```
app.MultiwidgetModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults : {
        ....
        operatorData        : {
                helloBlock  : null, 
                greeting    : null, 
                avatarBlock : null, 
                avatarImg   : null  
            },
        ....    
    },
    initialize: function(){
        var opData = this.get('operatorData');
        opData.helloBlock = 'foo';
        opData.greeting = 'bar';
        ...
        this.set({operatorData: opData}); // Without this, the data will change but you won't have a change:operatorData event triggered
    }
});
```

If you want to edit the default values you should be able to use

```
app.MultiwidgetModel.prototype.defaults.operatorData = {
    helloBlock  : 'foo', 
    greeting    : 'bar'  
}
```

Is that what you want?